# css resizing zoom complet website

Tags: css, resize

I am working on this project http://79.115.10.208:5000, and I found that my site is more beautiful if you change the firefox browser zoom to 90%. Does it exist some trick to do quick resizing using CSS?

Comment: You simply want everything to look smaller?

Comment: yes i want to everything to look smaller !

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your css

```
body { 
-moz-transform: scale(0.9, 0.9); /* Moz-browsers */
zoom: 0.9; /* Other non-webkit browsers */
zoom: 90%; /* Webkit browsers */
}
```

Comment: very nice solution, bat not working for my website, view this screen http://snag.gy/3MIVk.jpg